# Does Jekyll provide a method for extending a master Sass file without importing it?

Tags: sass, jekyll

I am referencing a master `base.scss` for global styles while working on multiple sites in a single Jekyll project. My project directory looks like this:

`project
 |
 +--_sass
 |   |
 |   +--base.scss
 |
 +--_site
 |   |
 |   +--apple
 |   |   |
 |   |   +--css
 |   |       |
 |   |       +--style.css
 |   |
 |   +--banana
 |       |
 |       +--css
 |           |
 |           +--style.css
 |
 +--apple
 |   |
 |   +--css
 |       |
 |       +--style.scss
 |
 |--banana
 |   |
 |   +--css
 |       |
 |       +--style.scss`

This works well because each of the `style.scss` files uses `@import` to import the `base.scss` file, which allows me to `@extend` the base styles in turn. This of course duplicates the content of `base.scss` across each file that imports it.

I'm wondering if there's a way to compile `base.scss` to say `_site/css/base.css`, which I would reference from my shared header, while retaining access to its classes when editing my site-specific Sass.

**Does Jekyll provide a method for *referencing* and *extending* Sass files without duplicating their contents in the build?**

Comment: I thought about using Sass placeholders throughout my base stylesheet, but the reward would be very small since these are common styles which would end up being imported to each site anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, the following arrangement should work just as fine:

```
project
 |
 +--_sass
 |   |
 |   +--base.scss
 |
 +--_css
 |   |
 |   +--main.scss
 |
 +--apples
 |   |
 |   +--css
 |   |   |
 |   |   +--style.css
```

```sass
/* css/main.scss */
---
---
@import "base";
```

```sass
/* apples/css/style.css */
/* No need of front matter dashes here if its not a sass file */

.my_class { color: blue; }
```

```html
<!-- _site/index.html -->
<head>
  [...]
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/apples/css/style.css" />
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. My question was a shot in the dark, and your answer isn't quite the solution. Going off your example, I was looking for a way to be able to `.my_class { @extend .color-blue; }` from `apples/css/style.css` without including `base.scss` in that and every other directory where I want to reference the base file. That is, compiling to a shared `main.css` file as you did but retaining access to its classes from which to extend. This is *not* a feature of Sass — Jekyll has surprised me with some of the things it offers, so I was wondering if maybe it provides a handler for this.